# Place in a different line phrases inside paste()

Tags: r, r-leaflet

How can I place in a different line Country Rate and Denominator in the label in R?

```
paste0("County:"
        , "Belgium","<br>",
        
        "Rate:"
        , 4.56,
        
        "Denominator:"
        , 2.58
        
 )
```

this is going to be used inside a leaflet map gor hoverinfo I do not know if this is important.

```
leaflet(oh_sp) %>%
      setView(lng = -118.2437, lat = 34.0522, zoom = 7)%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron")%>%
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(Rate),
        weight = 2,
        opacity = 1,
        color = "white",
        dashArray = "3",
        fillOpacity = 0.7,
        highlightOptions = highlightOptions(
          weight = 5,
          color = "#666",
          dashArray = "",
          fillOpacity = 0.7,
          bringToFront = TRUE),
        label = paste0("County:"
                        , oh_sp$County,
                        
                        "Rate:"
                        , oh_sp$Rate,
                        
                        "Denominator:"
                        , oh_sp$Denominator

        )
```

Comment: use a line break/line feed. I believe `<br>` is the line break for html,if rendering to text `\n` would be conisdered as line break. Not quite sure what linebreak is used within leaflet. Some platform allow for customized line breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of `leaflet` you have to add line breaks using an (additional) `<br>` tag as you already did for the first line. However, to render the the label as HTML you also have to wrap in `HTML()` and in case of a vector of labels you have to use `lapply` to apply `HTML()` on each element of the vector.

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(
    lng = c(174.768, 174.7),
    lat = c(-36.852, -36),
    label = lapply(
      paste0(
        "County: ", c("Belgium", "Somewhere"), "<br>",
        "Rate: ", c(4.56, 2.58), "<br>",
        "Denominator: ", c(2.58, 4.56)
      ),
      HTML
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake and, more as a comment on the earlier answer by stefan than a critique:

in addition to wrapping your HTML code in `htmltools::HTML()` and passing it to `label` you can consider instead passing it to `popup` as it is.

For some reason the `popup` argument renders as HTML out of the box, and does not require explicit declaration of HTML like `label` does.

On the other hand popup is displayed on click, whereas label on mouseover. Which may be, and may not be, relevant in your use case.

```r
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(
    lng = c(174.768, 174.7),
    lat = c(-36.852, -36),
    popup = 
      paste0(
        "County: ", c("Belgium", "Somewhere"), "<br>",
        "Rate: ", c(4.56, 2.58), "<br>",
        "Denominator: ", c(2.58, 4.56)
      )
  )
```

[image: a map with a popup instead of label]